# How to display dynamic variable in Jmeter report?

Tags: jmeter

I have a HTTP request , which will start at time , this value am storing in string variable beforetime
String beforetime=${​​​​​__time(,)}​​​​​;
Before Time ----> 1611822129009
This transaction will be saved in database with modified_date as 2021-01-28 13:08:30.923
I am extracting time from modified_date as below
String CurrentTime1=${__groovy(${__groovy(Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS','${Modified_date_1}').getTime(),)},)} ;

Now current time is --->1611822133322
the difference between this two is difference ---->4313

1. the difference between this two time is not actual time(it is calculated by converting to string), how to get the actual difference ?
   2)I need to populate the difference time for each HTTP request dynamically in Jmeter report , can you help me to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Given you have:

- JMeter Variable `${before_time)` with the value of `1611822129009`
- JMeter Variable `${modified_date)` with the value of `1611822133322`

[image]

You can calculate the difference and store it into another JMeter Variable using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
def before = vars.get('before_time') as long
def after = vars.get('modified_date') as long

log.info('Before: ' + before)
log.info('After: ' + after)

def difference = after - before

log.info('Difference: ' + difference)

vars.put('difference', difference as String)
```

The above code subtracts `before_time` from the `modified_date` and stores the result into `difference` JMeter Variable

[image]

Now you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
sample_variables=difference
```

and next time you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) the .jtl results file will contain the `${difference}` variable value for each sampler. You can even plot the value as a custom chart in the HTML Reporting Dashboard

More information:

- [Sample Variables Property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Generating customs graphs over time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)